# What happens when a player controls multiple identical monsters?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

The rules already specify that when multiple players have the same Monster Card, all monsters of that type will activate when any single monster acts.

When drawing new Monster Cards, if you already have the monster you draw, you discard it and draw again. However, some effects result in players passing Monster Cards around (causing monsters to activate more or less often).

If a player ends up with two of the same Monster Card, do they activate both monsters twice during their Villain Phase? Or do you put both cards together and activate the pair of them at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't specify which specific game in the *Dungeons and Dragons Adventure System* you're referring to, the following excerpt is from the [Wrath of Ashardalon rulebook](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Wrath_Ashardalon_RuleBook.pdf)

> Place a Monster on the new tile. To place a Monster, draw a Monster Card and place the corresponding Monster figure on the scorch mark of the newly placed Dungeon Tile. (The name of each Monster is printed on each figure’s base.) **If you draw a Monster Card that matches a Monster Card already in play in front of you, discard that Monster Card and draw again.** If another player has a matching Monster Card, however, that’s okay *(emph added)*

This states that you cannot have this situation, as you should have discarded the matching card in favor of a re-drawn, unique (to you) monster.

What this doesn't answer, however, is when there is an option to pass a monster or being forced to pass a monster.  Looking through the rules of both old (i.e. Wrath of Ashardalon) and new (i.e. Temple of Elemental Evil), I don't see this directly addressed anywhere, even in FAQs.  However, I think that we can refer to the spirit of the rules rather than the letter of them in order to resolve this.

One concept that **does** occur frequently within the rules/FAQ is that no single player may have more than one copy of a monster.  So, if you attempt to pass a monster to the right, but your right neighbor has a copy, either that pass is forfeited or the attempted pass continues further to the right.  Given that there are monster cards that force passing, I believe that the intent would be to continue the pass further around the table.  If everyone else has a copy, then ultimately it winds up being passed back to the original owner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this situation applies when drawing new monsters. Sometimes the games instructs players to pass monster cards. Does anything in the rules cover/forbid this for duplicates?

Comment: Also your I like your username, it gave me a lel! (badum tsk)

Comment: Thanks.  I responded in the original answer so that components weren't split between answer and comments.